# Docker Swarm Service Clustering

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I want to use docker-compose with Docker Swarm (I use docker version 1.13 and compose with `version: '3'` syntax).
Is each service reachable as a "single" service to the other services? Here is an simplified example to be clear:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    image: mynodeapp
    container_name: my_app
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=my_redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
    networks:
      - my_net
    command: npm start

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: my_redis
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 6379
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
    networks:
      - my_net

networks:
  my_net:
    external: true
```

Let's say I have 3 VMs which are configured as a swarm. So there is one nodejs container running on each VM but there are only two redis container.

On the VM where **no** redis is running: Will my nodejs container know about the redis?

Addiitonal questions:
When I set `replicas: 4` for my redis, I will have **two** redis container on **one** VM: Will this be a problem for my nodejs app?

Last question:
When I set `replicas: 4` for my nodeapp: Will this even work because I now have exposed **two** times port 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same order you asked:

1. One service does not see another service as if it is made of replicas. Nodejs will see a unique Redis, which will have one IP, no matter in which node its replicas are located. That's the beauty of Swarm.
2. Yes, you can have Nodejs in one node and Redis in another node and they will be visible to each other. That's what the manager does; make the containers "believe" they are running on the same machine.
3. Also, you can have many replicas in the same node without a problem; they will be perceived as a whole. In fact, they use the same volume.
4. And last, as implication of (1), there will be no problem because you are not actually exposing port 80 twice. Even having 20 replicas, you have a unique entrypoint to your service, a particular IP:PORT direction.

Comment: 3. But if I have a replicated database on **different nodes**, I have to configure a cluster for the database, because I need synchronized data -correct?

Comment: @Munchkin I'm not sure what you mean by this. Docker Swarm ensures you will have synchronized data no matter how many replicas your service has and how many nodes they are spread across, you don't have to worry about that aspect.

Comment: To be clear: e.g. I have 3 replicated redis. First request arrives at redis#1 and it will update key1. Then, later, another request arrives at redis#2: Does redis#2 have the new (updated) key? Even **without configuring a redis-cluster** (option `cluster-enabled yes`)?

Comment: And what about volumes? I found the `--mount` option... Will *all* replicated instances of redis (or mysql, elasticsearch, ...) mount the *same* volume? Won't there be any race conditions?

Comment: The two replicas of redis will have different data, they won't share a volume as stated in point 3.

Answer (score 1):

The services have to be stateless. In the case of databases it is necessary to set the cluster mode in each instance, since they are statefull.

Comment: "in each instance" - so do i really have so ssh (`docker exec -it container /bin/sh`) into every instance? Meh, that sounds like a bad workaround =/

Comment: The configuration will depend on each particular solution (statefull)        For example for couchbase, look at this example.
Https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-cluster-docker-swarm-compose-machine/
And this very good article related
Https://blog.couchbase.com/deploy-docker-compose-services-swarm/

regards